# Different version of the NetLogo extension API

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to run a Netlogo script that has been built with version 5.0.5. I just downloaded the version 5.0.5 a few days ago. The script uses the nw and time extensions. When I open my script, I obtain these error messages and I don't know how to resolve these problems:

[image]

> NetLogo is unable to supply you with more details about this error. 
>   Please report the problem at
>   https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues, or to
>   bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu, and paste the contents of this window into
>   your report.
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: time/TimeExtension :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)  at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)  at
>   java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:627)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)  at
>   org.nlogo.workspace.ExtensionManager.getClassManager(ExtensionManager.java:406)
>   at
>   org.nlogo.workspace.ExtensionManager.importExtension(ExtensionManager.java:173)
>   at
>   org.nlogo.compiler.StructureParser.parseImport(StructureParser.scala:459)
>   at org.nlogo.compiler.StructureParser.parse(StructureParser.scala:196)
>   at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:25)  at
>   org.nlogo.compiler.Compiler$.compileProgram(Compiler.scala:28)  at
>   org.nlogo.window.CompilerManager.compileProcedures(CompilerManager.java:107)
>   at
>   org.nlogo.window.CompilerManager.compileAll(CompilerManager.java:87) 
>   at org.nlogo.window.CompilerManager.handle(CompilerManager.java:309) 
>   at
>   org.nlogo.window.Events$CompileAllEvent.beHandledBy(Events.java:175) 
>   at org.nlogo.window.Event.doRaise(Event.java:198)  at
>   org.nlogo.window.Event.raise(Event.java:122)  at
>   org.nlogo.app.ProceduresTab$CompileAction.actionPerformed(ProceduresTab.scala:60)
>   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
>   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
>   at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
>   at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
>   at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
>   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6297)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6062)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4660)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
>   at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236) 
>   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166) 
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:674)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>   at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:647)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:645)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:644)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169) 
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161) 
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
>
> NetLogo 5.0.5 main: org.nlogo.app.AppFrame thread: AWT-EventQueue-0
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.6.0_45 (Sun Microsystems Inc.;
>   1.6.0_45-b06) operating system: Windows 7 6.1 (x86 processor) Scala version 2.9.2 JOGL: (3D View not initialized) OpenGL Graphics: (3D
>   View not initialized) model: IBM
>
> 11:16:19.654 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2
>   (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0 11:16:19.654
>   InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2
>   (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0 11:16:19.654
>   InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2
>   (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0 11:16:19.654
>   InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2
>   (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0 11:16:19.654
>   InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2
>   (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0 11:16:19.654
>   InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2
>   (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0 11:16:19.654
>   InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2
>   (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0 11:16:19.654
>   InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2
>   (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0 11:16:19.654
>   InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2
>   (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0 11:16:19.654
>   InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.InterfacePanel$2
>   (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0